# Using multiple select statement inside insert statement in Hive

Tags: shell, apache-spark, hive, bigdata

I'm new in Hive. I have three tables like this:

```
    table1:
        
        id;value
        1;val1
        2;val2
        3;val3
    
    table2
    
        num;desc;refVal
        1;desc;0
        2;descd;0
        3;desc;0

I want to create a new table3 that contains:

num;desc;refVal
    1;desc;3
    2;descd;3
    3;desc;3

Where num and desc are columns from table2 and refVal is the max value of column id in table1
```

Can someone guide me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to create an table to hold this.

```
CREATE TABLE my_new_table;
```

After that, you have to insert into this table, as showed [here](https://dwgeek.com/hive-insert-from-select-statement-and-examples.html/#:%7E:text=File%20and%20Examples.-,INSERT%20INTO%20table%20using%20SELECT%20clause,SELECT%20statement%20with%20INSERT%20command.)

```
INSERT INTO TABLE my_new_table 
    [PARTITION (partcol1=val1, partcol2=val2 ...)]
      select_statement1;
```

In the `select_statement1` you can use the same select you would normally use to join and select the columns you need.

For more informations, you can check [here](https://dwgeek.com/hive-insert-from-select-statement-and-examples.html/#:%7E:text=File%20and%20Examples.-,INSERT%20INTO%20table%20using%20SELECT%20clause,SELECT%20statement%20with%20INSERT%20command.)